# Unity ARCore XR settings and Vuforia enable(or switch) at Runtime in Android UnityPlayer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arcore

I am adding UnityPlayer inside Android View. I am trying to use 2 different scenes for AR in Unity.
Scene: 1 => Welcome screen to decide,device supports ARCore
Scene: 2 => If the device supports ARCore, launch ARcore scene from my Android Activity
Scene : 3 => If the device does not support ARCore, launch Vuforia scene from my Android Activity

So, for scene 1, I need to enable ARCore Supported in XR Settings
For scene 2, I need to enable Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported in XR settings
Not able to enable both options.
So is it possible to set these options at runtime, before launching Unity Player from my Activity?

Comment: Yes,that answer completely disable/enable XR settings.But my question is,how to enable particualar XR settings,either Vuforia or ARCore.

Comment: I might run into similar situation. could you show how add unity scene and player into android view? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't currently do this now but this might change in the future. The reason is because there is no way to disable ARCore at this moment. You can probably suggest that as a feature on their [Github](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk) page and explain you need it.

For *Vuforia*, you can disable it with `VuforiaBehaviour.Instance.enabled = false;` and `enable` it by setting it to true again.

The problem is that you can't do the-same with ARCore. You *might* be able to do the-same thing by finding all ARCore components in the scene and disabling them but I am not sure if that will release the camera or even work at-all.

Comment: Great...so I plan to use ARCore as native Java code and Vuforia with Unity.

Comment: As a temporary solution, you can do that now. Use ARCore as native Java code, then Vuforia with Unity. You can then make your game menu with Android Studio and Java. Here you can load Unity's app i you wish or your ARCore native app. That should work. The bad side is that you will be writing one program in Java and the other one in C# which makes code portability impossible.

Comment: I am using Vuforia as a temporary solution,as ARCore supported devices minimal.Once ARCore released,I will move to ARCore completely, because it is more accurate than Vuforia.

Comment: Ok. I am not an AR guy and don't know their differences. One question though: Vuforia is not free, right? Is ARCore also not free?

Comment: Vuforia is free for particular features like User Defined Target & Ground Plane supports only.Need to purchase license,when we use cloud based targets. But ARCore is free,as it from Google.